# Shape descriptor

Tags: image-processing, shapes, contour

I have an image which is a binary mask, I want to characterize the contours of the black zones in the mask, I have found several functionalities to detect the borders between both zones but only as a new image but what I want is the description of this border, not a new image. Is there any functionality in Java advance imaging or in another library which can be applied on the mask to retrieve a representation of the geometrical shape of black zones? The representation can be either a vectorization of the shape, a polygonal approximation, chain code... All I have found about is theoretical solutions for the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Are you comfortable writing a routine that walks the boundary and collects a list of the boundary pixels?  If you had such a list, would it let you form the descriptor you have in mind?

Answer (score 0):

You may try histogram based descriptors such as SIFT, SURF etc. In OpenCV, couple of advanced level descriptors are [implemented](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/common_interfaces_for_feature_detection_and_descriptor_extraction.html#descriptorextractor)
If your descriptors requires to be affine-covariant(scale and rotation invariant), I strongly recommend you to try SIFT. [Local binary pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_binary_patterns) is also an efficient choice.